# How to pass command line options to the Java Plugin on mac (without using the Java Preferences pane)

Tags: java, macos

I'm developing a Java applet and I'd like to debug it using eclipse, while it's running in a browser.

Debugging an applet in a browser requires passing special command line parameters to the java plugin (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557889/765287)).  In the past, I specified these parameters using the Java preferences pane in my Mac's System Preferences. Since [a recent software update](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57533880-263/java-preferences-missing-after-latest-os-x-java-update/) removed this preferences pane from OSX, however, it's no longer possible to use it to pass command line arguments to the JVM.  Does anyone know how I can pass start up parameters to Java, without using the preferences pane?

*EDIT*

I tried reinstalling the Java Preferences pane, as suggested by @marctrem. The reinstalled version doesn't seem to work properly. It allows me to enter options, but they don't have any effect. Also they aren't saved; when I reopen the pane any previously entered settings are gone.

Comment: *"command line options"*  When it comes to applets, there is no command line.  What options specifically?

Comment: By "command line options" I mean these specifically: "-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2502,server=y,suspend=n".

Comment: I got them from this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2557889/765287

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled OS X just to get this Prefpane back so I can backup it! It was on my desktop so I put it on Zippy! [Java Prefpane](http://www64.zippyshare.com/v/16944712/file.html)

I would also suggest you to install a newer JDK [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) or [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net)

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, though, the file up on Zippy won't run on my system. I'm on os 10.7.5 and it claims I need 10.8.  I'm trying to download a new JDK from oracle instead.

Comment: If you're using TimeMachine you can get your executable back! Or you could switch to 10.8 :) Java tastes like it should over here!

Comment: Good call re: Time Machine. :) I found the file in Applications/Utilities.  In case it helps anyone, I've posted it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10194257/Java_Preferences.zip