# Java 7 Debug on Windows 8 not working

Tags: java, debugging, windows-8, applet, java-7

I am trying to debug an applet on Windows 8 using Java 1.7.0_21.

I have added the bleow to the runtime parameters.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

When I try to connect I get "Could not open connection to the host, on port 5005" error on both local and remote machines.

If I do a netstat -an I don't see any port 5005 listening. It seems the JVM is not opening the listening debug port.

I have added the port to the firewall and even completely disabled the firewall, but no difference.

Has anyone else here tried to debug Java 7 on Windows 8?

Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem; really trying to move away from an applet but we're stuck with it for now and with the new Win8/Java7 builds that have just arrived on our machines, we're having issues getting debug to work...

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem and can a little light on the issue. I don't have a solution yet, which is why I came here, but this may help find the answer.

The problem is in the actual run-time being launched by the JRE. If you look at the executable in the Java control panel, it will be javaw.exe. So you're adding the debug flags to that. If you use Process Explorer to look at the actual process that's running your applet, it's java.exe. I don't know if javaw.exe is just spawning java.exe then dying or what, but the flags are never getting passed onto java.exe.

If you go to the Java tab in the control panel, you used to be able to add another run-time there. Well, you still can, but after clicking OK then Apply on the next dialog tab, then clicking back into the Java tab, your added run-time will be gone.  None of the settings that I've modified have made the browser plugin get the run-time parameters passed on, which makes it impossible to debug the applet in the browser context.

Comment: BTW, I should have added... This is on Windows 7 64-bit. I don't think it's related to the version of the OS, but instead to the version of the JRE.

And in case I didn't make this clear, you don't need to mess around with the firewall or anything, or at least that's not the primary issue here. The issue is that Oracle's made it so that you can NOT pass command-line options onto the plugin, either intentionally or accidentally (more likely the latter).

Comment: Same problem here, same configuration. BTW Spanky and @user2028936 why are you trying to debug ? On my side, I have signature issues (mixed code warning) on an applet that was fully functionnal and warning-free on previous versions of java 7 and 6 ...

Comment: @Cerber, I'm debugging an applet that we use for uploading medical imaging data. We're forced to use applets for two reasons: sandbox data restrictions with most client technologies and application of some high-level technical libraries (dcm4che, our own data-anonymization libraries) on the data before it's uploaded into our system. For the signature issues, try running jarsigner -verbose -verify on all of the jars in the applet. We haven't seen any signing issues on the recent JVM versions, just this debug problem.

Comment: lol, world is small : mine too is a medical applet. I found the roots of my problem not in the signature itself but in the browser<->applet interco (aka. LiveConnect) which seems to have been restricted in 7u21

Answer (score 2):

Did it ... almost !

Since I'm stuck I did it the hard way : replaced java exe by one of my own which forced java into debug mode

(please be gentle this is not high quality dev :) )

- backup your original java.exe and replace it with this fake java.
- don't forget to update `exeFile` to point to your java dir
- don't forget to update `stdoutRedirect` and `stderrRedirect` too
- use compilation options `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` for mingW

fakeJava.exe

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<strings.h>
int main(int givenArgc,char *givenArgv[])
{ 
    std::cout<<"step 0.a\n";
    char exeFile[] = "c:\\java\\jdk1.7.0_21\\bin\\java.exe";
    int prependArgc = 4;
    char* prependArgv[] = {
        "-Djava.compiler=NONE",
        "-Xnoagent",
        "-Xdebug",
        "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=2502,server=y,suspend=y"
    };


    std::cout<<"step 0.b\n";
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char date [80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (date,80,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S",timeinfo);

    std::cout<<"step 0.c\n";
    char stderrRedirect[100];
    char stdoutRedirect[100];
    sprintf(stderrRedirect,"2>d:\\tmp\\%s-stderr.txt",date);
    sprintf(stdoutRedirect,">d:\\tmp\\%s-stdout.txt",date);

    std::cout<<"step 0.d\n";
    int appendArgc = 2;
    char* appendArgv[] = {
        stderrRedirect,
        stdoutRedirect
    };

    std::cout<<"step 0.e\n";
    int argc = prependArgc+givenArgc-1+appendArgc;
    char** argv = (char**)malloc(argc*sizeof(char*)); 

    std::cout<<"step 1.a\n";
    char** src = prependArgv;
    int nbItems = prependArgc;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<nbItems;i++){
        argv[j++]=src[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"step 1.b\n";
    src = givenArgv;
    nbItems = givenArgc;
    for(int i=1;i<nbItems;i++){
        argv[j++]=src[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"step 1.c\n";
    src = appendArgv;
    nbItems = appendArgc;
    for(int i=0;i<nbItems;i++){
        argv[j++]=src[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"step 3\n";
    char str[4096];
    strcpy(str,exeFile);
    std::cout<<"step 4\n";
    for(int i =0;i<argc;i++){
        strcat (str," ");
        strcat (str,argv[i]);
    }
    std::cout<<"step 5\n";
    std::cout<<"will run : ";
    std::cout<<str;

    std::cout<<"\nstep 6\n";
    system(str);
    free(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's brutal, @Cerber :) I'll give that a try later on. I ended up recreating the full browser stack (minus the JSObject) in the IntelliJ applet debug configuration. Total pain in the neck, but it's working. In the course of trying to work around this issue, I've now completely bricked Java in the browser on my Windows machine and can only run applets in Firefox on OS X! I can debug there (it's 7u17) but the JVM crashes right at the point where I want to step through my code :/

Comment: @SpankyQuigman try javaRA to unbrick your install : I bricked and unbricked mine as well in the process of creating this soft :p http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/

Answer (score 1):

I set the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8989" as it suggested in the [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017269) and it did the trick for me (at least in the Chrome)

There is a lot of bugs filled in sun bugs database related to that, and it seems it only resolved in java-8 (b97)
Here is the link to the [sun-bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8016005) which describe exactly the same problem
and here is the place you can [download java-8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) (b99 is the current build)