# How to populate Jtextarea from void method with system.out.println?

Tags: java, swing

I am using library that has `public void` method `init()` with `System.out.println()` in it.

And in my implementation I can only access method `init()` which is void, but unable to get output from sout to my gui component `JTextarea`.

Is it possible to catch it (with `InputStream` or with some other way)?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Why don't just use `textArea.setText(String)` instead of `System.out.print`?

Comment: Don't mix GUI programming with console programming.

Comment: If this is an `Applet`, turn on the console; related debugging strategies are shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/868111/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some exception errors from other correct answers, I decided to look bit further and found following wonderful class, works flawlessly!

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have access to the library and can change it (I would be somewhat suspicious of using a library that prints to System.out for a GUI app), you could do the following:

```
PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream newOut = new PrintStream(baos);

    System.setOut(newOut);

    OtherLib.init();

    textArea.setText(baos.toString());
} finally {
    System.setOut(oldOut);
}
```

Comment: Don't you hate it when you have the same answer and it's a 2 min difference?  +1 for having a code example.  And for using `ByteArrayOutputStream` cleverly (I didn't know about the `toString()` trick)

Comment: This is great, thanks beny23 and others! Though, is it possible to get output realtime? it is working/getting text to TextArea after operation is finished..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get fancy, you can reroute `System.Out` to your own [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) using [`System.setOut(PrintStream out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29).  At that point you can read that `PrintStream` using a [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).  That `InputStreamReader` can then populate your GUI.

This isn't exactly the recommended fashion of communicating within a JVM, but if that's what your library gives you, I guess that's what you have to work with.

But keep in mind, if you reroute `System.Out`, all methods using `System.Out` will use the new `PrintStream`.  That means nothing will get printed to your console anymore.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StandardOutReader extends JPanel{

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public StandardOutReader(){
        add(textArea);

        try {
            //create all your inputs/outputs
            PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
            final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);


            //A thread that will continuously read the reader, and post the output to the GUI
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        char[] cBuffer = new char[256]; //Buffer for reading
                        int bytesRead; // number of byts read in the last "read()" call
                        while((bytesRead = reader.read(cBuffer)) != -1){
                            //Copy over only the interesting bytes
                            final char[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(cBuffer, bytesRead);
                            //Tell the GUI to update
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textArea.append(new String(copy));
                                }});
                        }
                    }  catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  finally{
                        //Closing the reader
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }}).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new StandardOutReader());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Thread that randomly prints stuff.  Not part of the GUI stuff at all.
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long)(4000 * Math.random()));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Adding another phrase");
                }
            }}).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, is it possible to get it realtime? maybe using Swingworker or Listener. I found that there is addMessageListener(Listener<String> ll, Event event), maybe this can be used to make it realtime?! thanks

Comment: @feruz You can have a thread (off of the EDT) sitting in a while loop, constantly reading from the `InputStreamReader`.  As soon as it reads, it can publish to the GUI (using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`). Then everything will be as real-time as it can get.

Comment: Great, thanks... it is working, though I get exception: `java.io.IOException: Write end dead
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:311)
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
 at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)`

Comment: @feruz Yes, you'll get that exception because one end of the stream will always close before the other end.  It should be safe to ignore that exception.