# How to debug Java applets running in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, debugging

I need to debug a Java applet. For now, just getting a heap dump would be a big help, although running something like JavaSnoop would be even better.

The complication is that the applet is part of a complex website that only works in Internet Explorer. While it's theoretically possible to isolate the applet and run it independently, initial attempts to do this have failed.

I have attempted [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557889/2508995). However, the debug settings are not taking effect for the Java VM that is running the applet. Port 2502 is not listening. I have tried basic tweaks such as rebooting and running IE as administrator, which have not helped. I've also confirmed that the same command line allows me to debug a standalone Java application.

I'm running JDK 8 and IE 11 on Windows 7.

I'm wondering if IE interfaces with Java slightly differently, so it doesn't obey the Runtime Parameters I have specified in the Java Control Panel.