# Is there a separate thread involved for Event Handling?

Tags: java, multithreading

guys this is my code. The docs for the library used can be found at [processing library docs](https://processing.org/) and [unfolding maps library docs](http://unfolding%20maps%20library%20docs). It displays a Google Map in a canvas. The setup() method is called once and then the draw() method is called repeatedly. As soon as I press w button on keyboard the background becomes white as keyPressed() is called.

```
import processing.core.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;

public class MyDefaultEventExample extends PApplet {

    private UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup(){
        size (800, 600, OPENGL);
        map = new UnfoldingMap (this, 50, 50, 700, 500, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());

    }

    public void draw(){
        map.draw();
    }

    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == 'w'){
            background (255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I dont precisely understand what actually is happening behind the scenes. I have thought about it and understood something out of it. I dont know if I am correct or not. Please check if this is what actually happens.

According to me -

1. There is a main method in the PApplet class which gets called as soon as I run the program which is responsible for displaying the canvas and calling the setup() and draw() methods. The pseudocode(not very "precise", just to give a gist of what I feel) which can be used to describe this is

   ```
      public static void main (){

          PApplet myApplet = new PApplet();

          myApplet.displayCanvas(); //displays a default canvas with a default background lets say gray.
          myapplet.setup();// calls the setup method.

          /* code for creating and calling a separate thread to handle events. */

          // repeatedly calls the draw method until the user closes the canvas window and closes the program
          while(!windowClosed){ 
              myApplet.draw();
          }   
      }
   ```
2. Also the pseudocode(not very "precise", just to give a gist of what I feel) for listening to events which is in the seperate thread according to me should be something like this:

   ```
   while(!windowClosed){
       Event event = listenForEvents();
       handleEvent(event); // this accounts for calling keyPressed().
   }
   ```

Is this the right way of thinking or it all happens in the main thread itself inside the while loop or perhaps there are more than 2 threads involved. I have written what I feel. Any suggestions/ helps would be really appreciated  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this SO question:
[How do you debug Java Applets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868111/how-do-you-debug-java-applets)

There is instruction on how to debug applets and how to **list all threads**. You will be able to determine yourself if there are any worker threads or not .